# How to make one side of the paddle a bot, in java ping pong game?

Tags: java, processing

I am making a java ping pong game, and I want to make one side of the paddle to be a bot, so player can compete against the bot. I have already inputed the bot, but I want to improve on it. I tried to create a thread to pause the bot every x seconds, but failed. Please help to figure out a solution.

I have pre-programmed the paddle and the ball, including check collision that kind of stuff. The game can be considered complete. I just want to add a bot so it will be PVE

This is paddle code

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;

public class Paddle {
private char upKey, downKey;
private boolean upDown, downDown;
private float x,y,width,height,speed;
private int r,g,b; //colors
private int score;
private PFont scoreFont;

public Paddle(float x, float y, float w, float h, float s, char up, 
        char down, int r, int g, int b, int score, PFont f) {
    scoreFont = f;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    upKey = up;
    downKey = down;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    speed = s;
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    score = 0;
}

public void draw(PApplet p) {
    p.rectMode(PApplet.CENTER);
    p.noStroke();
    p.fill(r, g, b);
    p.rect(x, y, width, height);

    p.textFont(scoreFont, 46);
    p.fill(255);
    p.text(score, PongMain.SCR_W-x-15, 50);
}

public void handlePress(char key) {
    if(key == upKey)
        upDown = true;
    else if (key == downKey) 
        downDown = true;
}

public void handleRelease(char key) {
    if(key == upKey) {
        upDown = false;
        speed = 15;
    }
    else if (key == downKey) {
        downDown = false;
        speed = 15;
    }
}

public void update() {
    if(upDown) {
        y = (float) (y - speed * 1.1);
    }else if(downDown) {
        y = (float) (y + speed * 1.1);
    }
    if(this.y >= PongMain.SCR_H - this.height/2) {
        this.y = PongMain.SCR_H - this.height/2;
    }
    if(this.y <= 0 + this.height/2) {
        this.y = 0 + this.height/2;
    }
}

public void bot(Ball theBall){
    if( theBall.getY() < y){
        y = y - speed;
    }else{
        y = y + speed;
    }
}

public float getX() {
     return x;
}

public float getY() {
     return y;
}
```

This is ball code:

```
package ball;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Ball {
float x, y, diameter, speed;
float direction;
int color[] = new int [3];

public Ball(float x,float y,float diameter,float speed,float direction, int red, int green, int blue) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.direction = direction;
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    }

    public void draw(PApplet p) {
    p.noStroke();
    p.fill(color[0],color[1],color[2]);
    p.ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }

    public void update() {
    x+= speed * PApplet.cos(direction);
    y+= speed * PApplet.sin(direction);
    speed += 0.01;
    }

    private void reset() {
    y = PongMain.SCR_H/2;
    x = PongMain.SCR_W/2;

    int n = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    if (n == 0) {
        direction = ((float)Math.random()*70 +100);
    }else if (n == 1) {
        direction = (float)Math.random()*70 +100;
    }else if (n == 2) {
        direction = (float)Math.random()*70 +190;
    }else if (n == 3) {
        direction = (float)Math.random()*70 +280;
    }
    }

    public void checkCollision(Paddle lPad, Paddle rPad) {
    //if Bleft to the left of LpadRight
        //if  Bally <ytop >ybottom
     if(x <= diameter/2 ) {
         lPad.increScore();
            reset();
     }

     if(x + diameter/2 >= PongMain.SCR_W) {
         rPad.increScore();
            reset();
     }

     if (y <= diameter/2 || y+diameter/2 >= PongMain.SCR_H) {
        direction = -direction;
     }

    if(x-diameter/2 <= lPad.getX() + PongMain.PAD_W/2) {
        if(y<=lPad.getY()+ PongMain.PAD_H/2 && y>=lPad.getY()-PongMain.PAD_H/2) {
                direction = PApplet.PI - direction;
            }   
    }  

    if(x+diameter/2 >= rPad.getX() - PongMain.PAD_W/2) {
        if(y<=rPad.getY()+ PongMain.PAD_H/2 && y>=rPad.getY()-PongMain.PAD_H/2) {
                direction = PApplet.PI - direction;
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is main code:

```
   import processing.core.PApplet;
   import processing.core.PFont;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

 public class PongMain extends PApplet {
    final static public int SCR_W = 1000;
    final static public int SCR_H = 800;
    final static public int frameRate = 50;
    public static final int PAD_H = 150;
    public static final int PAD_W = 20;
    public static final int PADDING = 30;
    public static final int PAD_Speed = 15;
    public static final int Ball_Speed = 10;
    public static final int Winningscore = 5;

Ball theBall;
Paddle lPad;
Paddle rPad;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("PongMain");
    /**PongMain run = new PongMain();
    Thread thread = new Thread(run);
    thread.start();**/
}

public void settings(){
    size(SCR_W, SCR_H);
}

public void setup(){
    frameRate(frameRate);
    theBall = new Ball(SCR_W/2, SCR_H/2,30,Ball_Speed,PI/6,255,45,60);
    PFont f= createFont("Verdana", 16, true);
    lPad = new Paddle(PADDING, SCR_H/2,PAD_W, PAD_H, 
PAD_Speed,'w','s',255,43,80,0,f);
    rPad = new Paddle(SCR_W-PADDING,SCR_H/2, PAD_W, PAD_H, 
PAD_Speed,'i','k',50,79,80,0,f);
    }



/* Run once for every frame */
public void draw(){
    if(lPad.getScore() < Winningscore && rPad.getScore() < Winningscore) {
        lPad.update();
        rPad.update();
        background(0);
        theBall.draw(this);
        theBall.update();
        theBall.checkCollision(lPad, rPad);
        lPad.draw(this);
        rPad.draw(this);
    }else {
        PFont f= createFont("Verdana", 16, true);
        this.textFont(f, 46);
        this.fill(255);
        this.text("Game is ended! Try again?", SCR_W/2-300, SCR_H/2);
        this.text("Press R to restart!", SCR_W/2-200, SCR_H/2+100);
    }
    rPad.bot(theBall);
}

//The keyPressed() function is called once every time a key is pressed. 
//The key that was pressed is stored in the key variable. 
public void keyPressed() {
    lPad.handlePress(key);
    rPad.handlePress(key);
    if(key == 'r') {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setup();
    }
}

public void keyReleased() {
    lPad.handleRelease(key);
    rPad.handleRelease(key);
}

/**@Override
public void run() {
    rPad.bot(theBall);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}**/
}
```

I expect the right paddle to move along vertically with the ball, so it can catch the ball and bounce it back all the time.

Comment: Did you try something already? We won’t do the code for you, but we can help with specific problems relating to it.

Comment: I did not read all of the code to try to find out. So please describe what you tried. Did you code following the y coordinate? If yes what is missing? If no why not? Did you consider that programming a perfect bot (always on balls y coordinate) might not be the point of a bot which provide actual fun of playing? Please describe the features of your game. Can I hit with the paddles edge to change the reflection angle? Can I make the ball turn by hitting with a moving paddle, to create somethign of a curve ball?

Comment: These are the code I tried `public void bot(){
  if(Ball.getY() < y){
         y = y + speed;
     }else{
         y = y - speed;
     }
 } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're overcomplicating this a bit. You don't need a lot of fancy logic to make your game controlled by a bot. Something like this would probably get you pretty far:

```java
if(playerTwoY < ballY){
  // player two is above the ball, move player two down
  playerTwoY++;
}
else if(playerTwoY > ballY){
  // player two is below the ball, move player two up
  playerTwoY--;
}
```

If you run this code every frame, your player two will constantly update itself.

I would highly recommend getting something like this working first before you try to do anything more advanced. But after you get this working, there are a few things you could try:

- Only update the movement of the paddle every X seconds. This would give a more realistic (worse) reaction time to the bot.
- Add some randomness to the movement of the paddle. This would make the bot less predictable.
- Calculate the path of the ball and use that to control the bot. (This is pretty advanced and probably not necessary to get a working version of a bot.)

Comment: I have completed the bot function, but I cant figure out how to pause movement every few seconds.Pls help

Comment: @smallnoob That's great! Please ask any follow-up questions in their own post. Also please try to narrow your problem down to a [mcve] instead of posting your full code. Hint: can you print a message to the console every few seconds? Get that working first.

Comment: I have posted another question just about pausing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503740/how-to-make-the-bot-pause-every-few-seconds-in-java-ping-pong-game